# Display every value in Android GraphView with a bigger point

Tags: android-graphview

Is there an opportunity to add for each value in Graphview a bigger point?
Like it's done in google analaytics for example:
http://www.cutroni.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2007/12/20071211-compre-two-metrics.png

I think it would make the data look way better ;-)

Answer (score 2):

yes it's is possible since the new version GraphView 3.1.1.

From the [Documentation](http://android-graphview.org/#doc_datapoints):

You can set the flag to let the GraphView draw circles at the data points.

```
LineGraphView graphView = new LineGraphView(
      this // context
      , "GraphViewDemo" // heading
);
graphView.setDrawDataPoints(true);
graphView.setDataPointsRadius(15f);
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Ok, thank you! Didn't see before. Also I don't find how to change colour and thickness of LineGraph. Did I also miss that in the documentation?

Comment: If you have only one data point, LineGraphView will not show it!

Comment: @Ashkan If you add it twice it will be show (and look like a single point)